# Using a macro/script to open a hyperlink in Excel - How to bypass the security of opening a file?

Tags: excel, security, browser

When you click a link in an Excel workbook, you get a warning 'Some files contain virus ... Would you like to open this file?'

Is there a way to turn this off/include it in a macro or script?

I have a macro that opens the link, but you have to manually click 'Yes' to keep the macro running. I want to run the macro and not have to do any user inputs. I've google'd it and there's a bunch of Registry Edit methods which don't seem to work for me. Any other ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reason for the macro runs to be prevented per default. Power plants have been attacked successfully because someone did run an Excel macro. The world would be a better place if the macros never existed. Look at least over the first 10 minutes.

https://youtu.be/xVBaPZqoLkc?t=910

Answer (score 0):

Security that can be bypassed is no security! Actually that is why you cannot bypass security.

There is no way to bypass this warning. The messeage is there for a good reason.
Otherwise your macro could download a dangerous file and run the code in that file without warning the user.